# How configure dblink from Oracle to Postgresql?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, dblink

Good afternoon, I want to get in dblink Postgresql of Oracle XE. But after configuration changes to the database server crashes.
Please see our seasoned professionals in the eye.

Oracle XE 11g r2 / PostgreSQL 9.5 / odbc-postgresql 1:09.05.0400-1

## listener.ora Network Configuration File:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )

    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PG_LINK)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = StatServ2)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 5432))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

## tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = StatServ2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

PG_LINK =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 5432))
      (CONNECT_DATA = 
        (SID = PG_LINK))
      (HS = OK)
  )
```

## initPG_LINK.ora Configuration File:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = PG_LINK 
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 0 
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

## /etc/odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
  PG_LINK = PostgreSQL

[PG_LINK]
  Debug = 1
  CommLog = 1
  ReadOnly = no
  Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
  Servername = localhost
  FetchBufferSize = 99
  Username = postgres
  Password = QWEasd07
  Port = 5432
  Database = stat_db

[Default]
  Driver = /usr/lib64/liboplodbcS.so
```

Comment: I fixed some minor bugs, but with parameter PROGRAM = dg4odbc database falls. With parameter (PROGRAM = hsodbc) there is a positive response tnsping, but does not work request to test table via a link.